# How can I interpret @expand_dims within a Python Class?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and I am trying to use the function '`one_hot_to_label_batch`' which can be found on line 115 from this [website](https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/data/isprs.py).

However, directly above this function there is a '`@expand_dims`'. This is the first time I have encountered this. I know '`expand_dims`' is within `Numpy` but I do not know why it is defined as '`@expand_dims`' here. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I found it at that website. It's a wrapper for the numpy function.  You'll find the code in a `utils.py` file up a level or two.

Comment: https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/data/utils.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a decorator. See the top of the [file](https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/data/isprs.py):

```
from .util import expand_dims
```

From this line, we can tell the decorator is defined in the `util.py` file in the same directory. We search in the `util.py` file, you can find the following function:

```
def expand_dims(func):
    def wrapper(self, batch):
        ndim = batch.ndim
        if ndim == 3:
            batch = np.expand_dims(batch, axis=0)
        batch = func(self, batch)
        if ndim == 3:
            batch = np.squeeze(batch, axis=0)
        return batch
    return wrapper
```

The function above is taken from [this source](https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/data/utils.py)

You should check out decorators first if you are not familiar with that.

Comment: if I want to import the `one_hot_to_label_batch` function on line 115 from [here](https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/data/isprs.py) within a new python file in a different directory, how can I?

Comment: @unknown121 it will depend on the path that you are in. Try to search on import on relative/absolute path. Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path